# Progress bar in Python using rich

Tags: python

I am making a File Sharing Program using sockets in python. I wanna show the transfer progress by making use of progress bar in rich. But the progress bar is not properly synced with the transfer progress

sender script-

```py
import socket, os, time
from rich.console import Console
from rich.progress import Progress


HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 12345
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUFSIZ = 4096
FORMAT = "utf-8"
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"


console = Console()


FILENAMES = ["file.txt", "lol.txt"]
FILSIZ = [str(os.path.getsize(x)) for x in FILENAMES]


def send():
    """main function to send files"""
    console.clear()

    # creating a client socket
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(ADDR)
    print(client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode(FORMAT))

    # sending file data
    client.send(SEPARATOR.join(FILENAMES).encode(FORMAT))
    print(client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode(FORMAT))
    client.send(SEPARATOR.join(FILSIZ).encode(FORMAT))
    print(client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode(FORMAT))

    # sending files
    for idx, files in enumerate(FILENAMES):
        with open(files, "rb") as f, Progress() as progress:
            task = progress.add_task(f"Sending {files}", total=int(FILSIZ[idx]))

            client.send(f.read(int(FILSIZ[idx])))

            while not progress.finished:
                progress.update(task, advance="<AMOUNT_OF_DATA_OR_CHUNKS_SENT>")
                time.sleep(0.1)

        f.close()


    # closing connection
    client.close()

send()
```

receiver script - https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/avomadisox.py

afaik `advance` value must be amount of data or chunks sent(might be wrong here)... how do i calculate the amount of data sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main question asks for

- How to calculate the amount of data sent?

From *Real Python*'s [Socket Programming in Python (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/):

> The `.send()` method also behaves this way. It **returns the *number of bytes* sent**, which may be less than the size of the data passed in.

This means that you have to pass the returned `int` of [`socket.send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) to the parameter `advance` of [`progress.update()`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/progress.html#rich.progress.Progress.update) function (compare your "<AMOUNT_OF_DATA_OR_CHUNKS_SENT>"):

```
# (1) define the transfer function returning the bytes_sent
def transfer_to_socket(from_file, to_socket, size):
    bytes_to_read = int(size)
    chunk = from_file.read(bytes_to_read)
    
    # <AMOUNT_OF_DATA_OR_CHUNKS_SENT>
    return to_socket.send(chunk)  # may be: bytes_sent < len(chunk) < bytes_to_read 

# (2) replace the progress-loop with: 
while not progress.finished:
    bytes_sent = transfer_to_socket(f, client, FILSIZ[idx])
    progress.update(task, advance=bytes_sent)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 4):

[Rich's progress bars](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html) are nice!

For many use-cases, the [track](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/progress.html#rich.progress.Progress.track) function that wraps a [Sequence or Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.abc.html) will suffice:

```py
import time
from rich.progress import track

for i in track(range(100)):
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

To increment progress by a variable amount at each step, use [rich.progress.Progress](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html#advanced-usage).

This example might show something in the spirit of the original question. Just for fun, let's customize the progress bar while we're at it.

```py
import time
import random
from rich.progress import (
    BarColumn,
    Progress,
    SpinnerColumn,
    TaskProgressColumn,
    TimeElapsedColumn,
    TimeRemainingColumn,
)

def process(chunks):
    for chunk in chunks:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        yield chunk

chunks = [random.randint(1,20) for _ in range(100)]

progress_columns = (
    SpinnerColumn(),
    "[progress.description]{task.description}",
    BarColumn(),
    TaskProgressColumn(),
    "Elapsed:",
    TimeElapsedColumn(),
    "Remaining:",
    TimeRemainingColumn(),
)

with Progress(*progress_columns) as progress_bar:
    task = progress_bar.add_task("[blue]Downloading...", total=sum(chunks))
    for chunk in process(chunks):
        progress_bar.update(task, advance=chunk)
```

Note: The generator `process(chunks)` is a generic stand-in for the file sizes in original question. This answer is mostly for the benefit of those brought here by searching on something like "python rich.progress_bar.ProgressBar example".

Comment: Hi @cbare | to create a basic progress bar, i use ```with Progress() as progress:```, is there a way to add ```SpinnerColumn()``` without having to generate this bigger mapped object like a ```progress_columns```?

Comment: Hi @DigitalFarmer, I don't know of another way, but I'm far from an expert with rich.

Comment: Alright @cbare , anyway, thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: @DigitalFarmer It is (at least now), quite easy: see documentaiton here: https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html#columns ... so to summarize: `with Progress(SpinnerColumn(), *Progress.get_default_columns()) as progress: ...`.