# rich progress bar not showing correct results with sockets file sharing

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, progress-bar, rich

I have two scripts `sender.py` and `reciever.py`. i got the idea of calculating chunks recieved and chunks sent from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72314473/15328137).

but i got some different results. the progress bar completed 100% instantly as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWxBs.gif). am i doing something wrong?

**sender.py**

```py
import socket
from pip._vendor.rich.progress import (Progress,TextColumn,BarColumn,TransferSpeedColumn, DownloadColumn, TaskProgressColumn)

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1',9999))
filename = "C:\\Users\\usename\\Downloads\\ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
filesize = 4932407296
with Progress(TextColumn("[progress.description]{task.description}"), BarColumn(), TaskProgressColumn(), DownloadColumn(binary_units=True), TextColumn('at'), TransferSpeedColumn()) as progress:
    send_task = progress.add_task("Sending...", total=filesize)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data_sent = 0
        while True:
            data = f.read(102400)
            if not data:
                break
            data_sent += sock.send(data)
            progress.update(send_task, advance=data_sent)
sock.close()
```

**reviever.py**

```py
import socket
from pip._vendor.rich.progress import (Progress,TextColumn,BarColumn,TransferSpeedColumn, DownloadColumn, TaskProgressColumn)

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1",9999))
sock.listen(10) # Accepts up to 10 incoming connections..
conn, address = sock.accept()
filename = 'ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
filesize = 4932407296
print( address)
with Progress(TextColumn("[progress.description]{task.description}"), BarColumn(), TaskProgressColumn(), DownloadColumn(binary_units=True), TextColumn('at'), TransferSpeedColumn()) as progress:
    recv_task = progress.add_task("Recieving...", total=filesize)
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        data_recieved = 0
        while (data_recieved < filesize):
            data = conn.recv(102400)
            data_recieved += f.write(data)
            progress.update(recv_task, advance=data_recieved)
conn.close()
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `advance` will **add to the completed** value by the specified ammount while setting `completed` itself will **override** it.

Since `data_sent` and `data_received` are already sums, instead of

```py
progress.update(task, advance=amount)
```

You probably want

```py
progress.update(task, completed=amount)
```

---

Altenatively, you could also avoid keeping track of the total entirely, and just use the delta:

(**sender.py**)

```py
import socket
from pip._vendor.rich.progress import (Progress,TextColumn,BarColumn,TransferSpeedColumn, DownloadColumn, TaskProgressColumn)

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1',9999))
filename = "C:\\Users\\usename\\Downloads\\ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
filesize = 4932407296
with Progress(TextColumn("[progress.description]{task.description}"), BarColumn(), TaskProgressColumn(), DownloadColumn(binary_units=True), TextColumn('at'), TransferSpeedColumn()) as progress:
    send_task = progress.add_task("Sending...", total=filesize)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(102400)
            if not data:
                break
            delta = sock.send(data)
            progress.update(send_task, advance=delta)
sock.close()
```

Comment: it worked with `completed=amount`. but didn't get the second thing. what do you mean by delta? can you explain it with another example?

Comment: (Edit: I added the full code for clarity) I just called that value `delta` as it's technically the difference between the new value and the current value. You can think of it as **how much the bar has increased since the last time**.

If you only need them to draw the progress bar, this makes the `data_sent`/`data_received` variables redundant.